# challenge a deception accusation

Tags: uk, deception

i got denied entry at birmingham airport in nov 2009.
i had a valid residence student visa which they curtailed at port.
In the below refusal at port , the immigration officer said that my intention to coming UK was to work at HP singh elecrical wholesalers.

this was blurted out by me as they were pressing me for further information and my mind was in a trauma during their interrogation. they made me sign it.

But this is NOT true.

However i have never worked for that employer as i haven't..
 i was losing control of my head as i was in a trauma that day.
Hence there is no evidence as i have absolutely never worked for that employer.
If the home office contact him , then he will confirm that i have never worked for him, as i did not.

so my question is
can we challenge this false accusation of home office of 2009 and if so how?
i was on antidepressants breifly that year which was prescribed by a UK surgery.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95948/discussion-on-question-by-lindisingh-challenge-a-deception-accusation).

Answer (score 4):

Can we challenge this false accusation of intention to work? Possibly.

If so, how? Consult an Immigration lawyer who can advise you on whether a judicial review is possible almost 10 years after the event, the steps and timeframe involved, and the evidence you’ll need to provide.

This seems like a complicated situation and there’s little more that TSE members can say.

Comment: traveller i also have old school friends in the UK whom i want to visit, so which visa should i apply to visit my old collage friends in london then?

Comment: @lindisingh the standard visitor visa is the appropriate visa to visit friends. But all of the other information Traveller has provided still applies - based on what you've told us, you should not expect to receive any kind of UK visa any time soon.

Comment: chris 10 years have passed, i do not believe that old entry denial will be so strong so as to override my current circumstances, what you say is illogical

Comment: i think i will consult a lawyer as people here are a bit discouraging and non optimistic

Comment: @lindisingh You’ve asked questions about a) applying for a Tier 4 visa; b) transiting the UK; and c) a visitor visa. You’ve described a fairly complicated UK Immigration history, and now you comment that you don’t believe your old entry denial will be a sufficiently strong problem, set against your current circumstances (which you’ve not told us anything about). If you meet the criteria for a visitor visa, go ahead and apply. If you’ve got a question about doing so that doesn’t repeat your earlier questions, please post a separate question.

Comment: i have all my brothers western union money transfers and his employment letter and his letter of support

Comment: @lindisingh you've been advised multiple times that your travel history makes your case very tricky and you need the help of an expert immigration lawyer. The circumstances you just described are not *against* visitor visa rules, but they certainly don't make your case any simpler. **You need to speak to a lawyer**. That is the best advice anybody here is able to give you.

Comment: okay chris, you are right, i paid 2500 quid to a lawyer in 2018 and he got my 10 year ban removed which was imposed in 2012, so i guess another 1000 quid then for another lawyer

Comment: @lindisingh See, right there you gave further information. Your question stated that you were denied entry in 2009, and you have a 10 year ban which should be up this year. Now you say a lawyer got a 10 year ban removed which was imposed in 2012. What happened in 2012?? This is why people are saying you have a complicated history and circumstances.

Comment: @lindisingh what evidence do you have that the ban was actually revoked?  £2500 seems like a fraction of the real cost of the legal process necessary to get a ban revoked - are you sure you weren't just scammed?

Comment: @lindisingh Oh come on - are you kidding? A conviction for shoplifting, giving false names to the police, denial of entry after enrolment but failure to attend at an unauthorised college (lots of those caught up in immigration scams)... really, you say you have a US visa, perhaps best to stick with that and forget the UK

Comment: @lindisingh Doesn’t matter that the conviction is long spent, you’d still have to declare it. For example, the section on convictions and penalties in the Visitor visa application asks ‘Have you at any time...’