# transit through Heathrow - will I be questioned?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, lhr

i will be landing at Heathrow airport on my journey  from India to USA, will I be asked few questions by immigration or do they have time to dig into my ancient immigration history when I was a student in UK many years back.
I am an Indian holding a USA visa and been to USA 2 times before sleeping overnight at Heathrow, was frightened to approach passport control when I was there last time.

Comment: What do you fear? Do you maybe need a visa? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk

Comment: Yes, it would help to know what specifically you fear. Do you have an adverse immigration history from your student days or did that all go normally? Were there any problems when you went through passport control previously?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler someone with a US visa is eligible for transit without visa in the UK.

Comment: @lindisingh Just curious - if you’re so concerned about the possibility, why didn’t you book a flight with a different transit point? But having just found your earlier question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/141751/challenge-a-deception-accusation your concern makes more sense. Your UK history does seem much more complicated than the typical transit passenger.

Answer (score 4):

**If** (a) your flights are booked as one booking, (b) you're not transiting overnight, **and** (c) your luggage is checked through to the USA, **then** you shouldn't have to go through UK immigration at all, so it's very unlikely you'll even see a UK immigration officer.

Your airline will check that you're eligible to transit through the UK (a US visa means you should be good to go), but they won't ask any questions about your immigration history.

Comment: If your flights are booked as one booking, you're not transiting overnight -- that's not true, plenty of flights are one booking have an overnight transit in them, many routings do not even make it possible to do it otherwise.

Comment: @chx ‘You’re not transiting overnight’ isn’t a statement, it’s a second condition (if... and you’re not transiting)

Comment: Indeed @Traveller is right, thanks MadHatter for editing to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Given [your UK immigration history](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/141751/challenge-a-deception-accusation), yes, you might be questioned. It is difficult to fully understand your history (you were denied entry in 2009 and later received a 10 year ban in 2012 for some unspecified reason which was then supposedly overturned in 2018), but it's clear that it is complex and may require more scrutiny than can be sorted out quickly at the primary inspection booth, so you could be questioned while that is sorted out. That's particularly concerning because you apparently have a history of falsely confessing to immigration violations when questioned.

But you say that you were "frightened to approach passport control when I was there last time." It's unclear when that happened. If you've recently made the same trip through Heathrow without incident and nothing else has changed, it stands to reason that you're likely, but not certain, to receive the same treatment again this time.

Comment: Related question from OP https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17724/denied-entry-to-uk-in-2009-can-i-apply-for-a-student-visa-in-2019

Comment: i went through heathrow in 2017 but stayed in the airport lounge overnight , the ukvi people came to the lounge to check my passport but just saw my usa visa and i continued sleeping on the chairs, but then i had a 10 year ban so i did not approach passport control, my 10 year ban was overturned in november 2018, so this time in 2019 decem ber i want to stay overnight at a hotel as i have a 20 hour layover, so am frightened what will happen, but there is no ban in place now which was confirmed in an email from ukvi

Comment: @lindisingh Why are you even considering risking this? Isn’t there a less fraught transit option? There’s no airside hotel accommodation at LHR so you will need to clear Immigration. An overturned ban doesn’t mean you will necessarily sail through your landing interview or that they can’t deny you entry this time, even with your US visa and flight ticket as proof of onward travel.

Comment: the worst that they can do is tell me to go back airside, what is the risk

Comment: dear zach Lipton,  thanks for your amazing response, last time i was sleeping overnight at a terminal longe with some other travellers and so did not pass through immigration but at that time i had a ban on me, so am wondering what is the harm in trying now to stay at hyatt place hoel and have a comfortable sleep to catch my connecting flight next day

Comment: dear zach , yes i have a old entry denial from november 2009 but that will more than 10 years ago, so will that flag up or not?