# How long are biometrics at Heathrow airport kept?

Tags: uk, biometric-passports

I had my biometrics taken in 2009 November at Birmingham airport when I was denied entry to the UK. My question is if I go this December 2019 which is more than 10 years since that date, will my biometrics still be on record as I have heard that biometric records at Heathrow are retained for a maximum of 10 years, after which they are deleted.

So this time will I get flagged up ( which I shouldn't be as it is more than 10 years since that entry denial?

Comment: "Advance passenger information may be retained for 10 years" is mentioned in page 7 of https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/779876/borders-immigration-citizenship-system-privacy-notice.pdf you can contact your nearby uk embassy..

Comment: so does that mean that my 2009 nov entry denial will not be flagged up after 10 years from that date when they scan my passport at heathrow?

Comment: They don't need your biometrics to know you're the same person. They also have your passport data. Any non-visa national who has an adverse immigration history is best off applying for a visit visa rather than trying to enter visa free.

Comment: @lindisingh What makes you think API data is the same as denial of entry data?

Comment: @MJeffryes The OP isn’t a non-visa national, and has a complex back story with UK Immigration https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/147201/transit-through-heathrow-will-i-be-questioned

Comment: @Traveller Avoid transiting the UK IMO, but they've been told that before...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because with the OP’s complex UK immigration history it’s impossible to state what data will still be on file with any degree of certainty.

Answer (score 2):

From [this GOV document](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/779876/borders-immigration-citizenship-system-privacy-notice.pdf):

> At the border, passenger name records data is retained for 5 years.
>   Advance passenger information may be retained for 10 years.

**Note: Just because the API isn't retained, they can still know you are the same person**.

It also states:

> We will keep your personal information for as long as it is necessary for permitted purposes. In the Borders, Immigration and Citizenship System, we maintain a long-term record of immigration history and immigration offending to support future decision-making and enforce penalties.

Don’t assume that your data is no longer held just because 10 years have passed. Follow gov.uk advice and apply for a visa.

Comment: The word **may** does not imply it will be automatically deleted after 10 years.